# CLI - Error when disk parameter is in use

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

So i have a problem with softlayer vs creation, i try to create a vs from public image, but if i use --disk option i got an error.

Command:

```
vs create -H g0 -D example.org -c 1 -m 2048 -d ams01 --image 3c289880-2f63-48d3-906d-aaa9a822a6d0 --billing=monthly --vlan-public 1313131 --vlan-private 313131 --disk 25 --test
```

Error:

```
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue): Invalid value provided for 'blockDevices'. Block devices may not be provided when using an image template.
```

If i don't use --disk option it creates the instance fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates if you are specifying an image template you cannot set the disk size. It is automatically set to the same disk size as the image template.

" Block devices may not be provided when using an image template"